# Client and server side componets

Tags: adjectives, compounds, compound-adjectives

I'm having a problem to refer to the components that are in both, the client-side and the server-side.

I started writing: "client and server-side components"     (1)

I did that in order to avoid repeating "-side": client-side and server-side components     (2)

Maybe I should remove the "-", otherwise "side" is just applying to "server": client and server side components     (3)

But I think this could also be wrong since it is not a single side but two sides: client and server sides components     (4)

And maybe I should move "components" to the beginning:
components on the client and the server sides     (5)

I think the last alternative (5) is the right one, but not really sure if the reasoning is right.

Thanks for your time,
Gab

Comment: Client-side and server-side components. No other option works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One variation that you left out, and which is common, is the use of a suspended hyphen:

> client- and server-side components

From *The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.), 7.88:

> When the second part of a hyphenated expression is omitted, the suspended hyphen is retained, followed by a space (or, in a series, by a comma).
>
> fifteen- and twenty-year mortgages
>       Chicago- or Milwaukee-bound passengers
>       five-, ten-, and twenty-dollar bills